# DDS with AD9833 and Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, function-generator, dds

I'm working on a two channel DDS function generator for a project. I have done some research and I want to use the AD9833 IC controlled with a Microcontroller, an Atmel chip if possible since I have work with the Atmega328 before.

My question is, since I want two independent channels, how can I control two AD9833 chips with one Microcontroller?

Comment: It uses SPI, you can just have two devices and two chip selects. done.

Comment: FSYNC pin is the "chip enable" equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AD9833 has a standard 3-wire serial interface that is compatible with 
the Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI) standard. SPI support multiple devices with independent slave configuration. There is an independent chip select (SS) line for each slave. MOSI, MISO, and SCK are parallel for all slaves.

This connection should work:

- ATMega328 PB3/MOSI to SDATA AD9833 (both of them in
  parallel)
- ATMega328 PB5/SCK to SCLK AD9833 (both of them in
  parallel)
- Any ATMega328 ouput pin connected to FSYNC first AD9833 as chip
  select
- Any other ATMega328 ouput pin connected to FSYNC second AD9833 as chip
  select